# Insert special character in value

Tags: javascript, regex, input, textfield

I have a panel form in ExtJS and a textfield inside and I am trying to insert a `.` symbol before `*` in this textfield. I have a button that sends the value from this textfield to a server and returns me results.

In my code, I check if a string contains a `*` symbol, then I insert the `.` from this textfield into it.

Example of what I have now: I type in textfield `*test*` my code convert it to `*test.*`. What I need is `.*test.*`.

If I type in textfield `*t*st*` I need the `.*t.*st.*` as a result.

How I can insert the `.` symbol before every `*` symbol in my value string?

```js
fieldLabel: 'name',
name: 'name',
submitValue: true,
enableKeyEvents: true,      
  getSubmitValue: function () {
   var value = this.getValue();
   var format = /[*]+/; 
   let valTrimmed = value.slice(0, value.length -1); 
   var ts = '';
     if(format.test(value)){
     ts = valTrimmed + '.*';
     return ts;
 }              
  return value; 
}
```

Comment: Why not `getSubmitValue: function () { return this.getValue().replace(/\*/g, '.$&'); }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you can simply replace each `*` with itself and a `.` in front using

```js
getSubmitValue: function () { 
  return this.getValue().replace(/\*/g, '.$&'); 
}
```

Note that `/\*/g` regex matches all occurrences of `*` (escaped, since it is a special regex metacharacter) and the `$&` in the replacement pattern refers to the whole match.